# CMPedometer saving steps

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, core-motion

Im building an ios app, by which I need to save the timestamp of **each** step that the user makes. Im using CoreMotion CMPedometer, but the method startUpdates only outputs the total number of steps that the user did from a start time to a end time. Is there anyway I can get the exact step times ?

I also noticed that there is another available package that I can use to step counting, HealthKit. Can I use it to know the timestamps of the steps? (in case CMPedometer does not work).

Thanks!!

Comment: I doubt that you can get the timestamp of *each step*; You can use timestamps for each delivered `CMPedometerData` block or cadence data (if available) to determine the approximate number of steps per second but you could only infer a linear rate of steps, not determine a precise date for each step.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes exactly what I thought, thanks :)